# Dash dcc.DatePickerRange Colors

Tags: python, css, datepicker, plotly, plotly-dash

I'm trying to style a Dash date picker and am having trouble identifying the appropriate classes.

So far I have

```
.CalendarDay__selected,
.CalendarDay__selected:active,
.CalendarDay__selected:hover {
  background: gold;
  border: 1px double black;
  color: #fff
}

.CalendarDay__selected_span {
  background: #a17f1a;
  border: 1px double #black;
  color: #fff
}
```

which modifies what I think are the default plotly classes.

However there are lots of hover, border, active, etc. properties which aren't affected by these, so the default blueish color remains.

Does anyone know how to change the overall color scheme with minimal css please? Or perhaps by some property on the `dcc.DatePickerRange` component itself?